# div getting pushed around or not appearing by other divs

Tags: html, css

I have an animation for a div that looks like a heart and am trying to put some text next to the heart div when the animation finishes. I tried putting text in a div and positioning that next to the heart but the invisible part of the heart keeps pushing it around or sometimes the div with text isn't visible at all. some help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```css
  body {
  overflow: ;
}

#heart {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
  left: 300px;
  top: 200px;
  color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 5000px 5000px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5000px 5000px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  #lol {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 200px;
    font-family: Quicksand;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" />

<body>
  <div id="heart"></div>
  <div id="lol">#Forever Alone</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly missed the { after . That is,

```
100%{
    z-index:2;
}
#lol {
```

should be

```
100% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
#lol {
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The weird formatting is because you just need to add another closing bracket after you're done declaring your @keyframes (just before #lol).

```
#heart {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
  left: 300px;
  top: 200px;
  color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 5000px 5000px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5000px 5000px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
#lol {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  font-family: Quicksand;
  color: black;
}
```